# Android 2d Animation

Tags: android, 2d

I create ImageView with scr run01 (it's first frame of my animation)
In drawable I create xml file with this code:

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/run01" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/run02" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/run03" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/run04" android:duration="200" />

    </animation-list>
```

All file  .png format
I have problem with 2d animation

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class runImage extends AppCompatActivity {
  AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

protected void onWindowFocusChanged(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_run_image);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.run01);
    rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
    rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();            }
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        rocketAnimation.start();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I don't understand misstake:
AAPT err(Facade for 826652682): libpng error: Not a PNG file
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Comment: `All file .png format` contrasts with `libpng error: Not a PNG file`. Probably, some files in your `drawable` folder are **not** PNG files. Not strictly related to the animation frames

Comment: yes I have one .jpg file and several .xml files.
I study in this file and I have more 10 different activity, some of their use drawable

Comment: Then you found your culprit.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi we can have xml file in drawable .. I hope it won't give this error for that

Comment: `I have one .jpg file` **this** is the culprit. Obviously, not the xml files.

Comment: if I create directory in drawable drawable/animrun and send  run**.png 
I don't understand as correctly to specify a way to files
becouse
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/animrun/run01" android:duration="200" />
not worked

Comment: ... a folder under `drawable`?! NO.

Comment: Someone can answe what I can make that it would work?
Yes drawable have 5files xml, in this .xml I study drawing. I change .jpg file in PhotoShop on .png,  misstake don't change.
When I do new file this code is working, but in this project no