# libpng error: Not a PNG file Not showing file name Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I am new to android studio. I wanted to migrate from ADT to Studio.
Migration is done but while building it shows an error in gradle console.
Issue here it is not showing the name of drawable file so how can i find which file is not png.I have checked all files are in .png format.

**GRADLE CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

> AAPT err(Facade for 433443052): libpng error: Not a PNG file

**FAILED**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':PACKAGENAME:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 48.413 secs

Comment: *Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.*

Comment: @marmor i have more than 200 png files.i cannot open and save each and every file.

Comment: @selvin where to put these lines?

Comment: Similar question, asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873184/android-2d-animation#34873184

Comment: Only png files are there in drawable